# Undefined array? TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, undefined

I am trying to program an app using reactjs and am running into the error above.
I believe this means that my tasks array is undefined, but I think that is is defined so I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it. I think the error is around the array involving the .map. Thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task.js';

export default ({ tasks }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {tasks.map(task => (
        <li key={task.id} className="list-group-item">
          <Task task={task} />
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you passing a tasks prop when you render this component? What’s the value of the prop?

Comment: Yes I believe so. My main app code contains a const that defines tasks with some filler items.                                                                                                
import React from 'react';
import TaskList from './TaskList.js';

function App() {
  const tasks = [
    {id: 0, description: 'do this', done: false},
    {id: 1, description: 'do that', done: false},
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Comment: Error is telling you that `tasks` prop value is undefined. Can you update your question to include the parent component rendering this component and what & where the `tasks` value comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is totally fine.

but if you are getting the list from api and setting it in state then your problem is that at first render the tasks array will be undefined and you need to deal with it, maybe adding loading indicator or adding default value as empty array for tasks prop.

```
import React from "react";

const TaskList = ({ tasks = [] }) => {
  return (
    <ul className="list-group">
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <li key={task.id} className="list-group-item">
          {task.description}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

function App() {
  const tasks = [
    { id: 0, description: "do this", done: false },
    { id: 1, description: "do that", done: false }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <TaskList tasks={tasks} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```